# Change the XML File to txt File in Blob output stream

Tags: c#, xml, txt, azure-blob-trigger

This is my code :

```
[StorageAccount("BlobConnectionString")]
    public class copyBlobtoazureStorage
    {
        [FunctionName("copyBlobtoazureStorage")]
        public async Task Run(
            [BlobTrigger("input-file/{name}")] Stream inputBlob,
            [Blob("output-file/{name}", FileAccess.Write)] Stream outputBlob,
            string name, ILogger log, ExecutionContext context)
        {
            if (name.EndsWith(".xml"))
            {
                
                XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(inputBlob))
                {
                    doc.Load(reader);

                }

                string jsonText = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc);
                byte[] info = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes(jsonText);
                outputBlob.Write(info, 0, info.Length);
            }


            log.LogInformation($"C# Blob trigger function Processed blob\n Name:{name} \n Size: {inputBlob.Length} Bytes");


        }
    }
```

I want to change the xml file in the input file to text file in output file.
I tried to use {name}.txt but I got note.xml.txt but I just want note.txt !
any suggestion ?

Comment: Is the only bit that's causing a problem for you the name? If so, you know that the name ends with ".xml", so just use `Substring` to get the name before those four characters...

Comment: `name.Replace(".xml",".txt")`

Comment: @Luuk: That depends on whether there might be multiple parts, e.g. "xyz.xml.xml" - I'd expect that to become "xyz.xml.txt" rather than "xyz.txt.txt"

Comment: @JonSkeet: True, But the question implies not having double extensions. Why else would there be an attempt not to have "note.xml.txt" ? 

Comment: @Luuk: No, the question implies not *creating* a double extension when the input only had one extension. There's a huge difference those two.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Might be a language problem on my side then.... (sorry).

Comment: XML is a text file.  Maybe all you want to do is change the extension from xml to txt.